# Why my custom dialog can not close automatically?

Tags: android, dialog

I defined a CustomDialog class as follow :

```
public class CustomDialog {
    Dialog dialog;
    public void show(Contex contex, int duration){
        Handler timeHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
    case 1:
    dialog.dismiss();
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }               
    };
       dialog = new dialog(contex);
       dialog.show();
       Message message = new Message();
   message.what = 1 ;
   timeHandler.sendMessageDelayed(message, duration);
    }
}
```

In the Activity , I new an CustomDialog object , and call the show() method , but the dialog can not close automatically , could anybody tell me why ?
The code in the activity :

```
CustomDialog myDialog = new CustomDialog();
myDialog.show(this,2000);
```

It did not work.Is it a formal way to create a custom dialog ? If it's not , could anyone tell me what is the right way to create one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this:

    public class CustomDialog {
        Dialog dialog;
        public void show(Contex contex, int duration){
            Handler timeHandler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 1:
        dismiss();
        break;
        default:
        break;
        }               
        };
           dialog = new dialog(contex);
           dialog.show();Timer timer = new Timer();
Timer timer=new Timer(); 
   timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        //dismiss the dialog here
        dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, duration);

        }
    }
```